# replace html class when scrolling with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar, and if I want my web page in scrolling navbar will change class. And this my web page html

how do I replace navbar-up class with navbar-down on jquery?
I've seen some tutorials on various websites but still can not

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default top-postion navbar-up" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/kotakku-icon.png"> Kotakku</a>
</div>


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-tabs navbar-right navbar-menu" role ="tablist">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#product">Product</a></li>
    <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and this my web page css

```
.navbar-up{
border-radius: 0;
position: static;
width: 100%;
padding: 0 20px;
z-index: 99;
border-bottom: 4px solid #ffffff;
border-right: 0px;
border-left: 0px;
background-color: #ffffff;}

.navbar-up .navbar-brand{
color: #0E9000;
font-family: dosis;
font-size: 29px;
margin-top: -5.5px;}

.navbar-up .navbar-brand img{
width: 65px;}

.navbar-up .navbar-menu li a{
color: #0E9000;
font-size: 20px;}

.navbar-down{
border-radius: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
padding: 0 20px;
z-index: 99;
border-bottom: 4px solid #0E9000;
border-right: 0px;
border-left: 0px;}

.navbar-down .navbar-brand{
color: #0E9000;
font-family: dosis;
font-size: 27px;
margin-top: -5.5px;}

.navbar-down .navbar-brand img{
width: 52px;}

.navbar-down .navbar-menu li a{
font-size: 18px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make a JSFiddle and put the Fiddle link in your question? It is easier to let people to see where is your problem. 
However, I suggest you probably need to do something like:

```
$('nav').removeClass('navbar-up'); 
$('nav').addClass('navbar-down');
```

Comment: please explain more fully

Comment: @FaisalAyas, can you tell me what do you want to do by Jquery? So I can help you with your codes.